# Iterating through SortedSet in Java

Tags: java, sortedset

I am trying to create intervals for double values stored in a SortedSet.

Below is my code:

```
 public class Trail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortedSet<Double> val = new TreeSet<Double>();
        val.add(1.0);
        val.add(2.0);
        val.add(11.0);
        val.add(12.0);

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        double posinf = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        double neginf = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        arr.add(neginf+ " - " +val.first());
        Iterator<Double> it = val.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            // Get element
            Object lowerBound = it.next();
            Object upperBound = it.next();
            arr.add(lowerBound+" - "+upperBound);
        }
        arr.add(val.last() + " - "+ posinf);
        System.out.println("Range array: "+arr);
    }
 }
```

My current output is:

```
Range array: [-Infinity - 1.0, 1.0 - 2.0, 11.0 - 12.0, 12.0 - Infinity]
```

I expect range array as:

```
[-Infinity - 1.0, 1.0 - 2.0, 2.0 - 11.0, 11.0 - 12.0, 12.0 - Infinity]
```

Comment: doing it.next twice is moving the iterator twice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are consuming two elements in each iteration of your loop (which would have thrown an exception if the number of elements was odd). You should consume just one in each iteration :

```
    Iterator<Double> it = val.iterator();
    Double lowerBound = neginf;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        // Get element
        Double upperBound = it.next();
        arr.add(lowerBound+" - "+upperBound);
        lowerBound = upperBound;
    }
    arr.add(lowerBound  + " - "+ posinf);
```

Comment: You can also see from this answer that you need to retain each value for the next iteration, which is why the lowerBound variable has been moved outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Each it.next() call will forward the iterator with one step. Therefore in each iteration of your while loop you will loose one interval. Use a temporary variable to keep the previous iterator value.

For something like

```
Iterator<Double> it = val.iterator();
Object end=null;
if(it.hasNext()){
    end= it.next();
    //write out -infinity to previous.
}
while(it.hasNext()){
    Object start = end;
    end= it.next();
    //write out start - end interval
}
if(end != null){
// write out end to infinity 
} else {
   // there were no values in the array.
   // write out - infinity to infinity?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in following loop

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    // Get element
    Object lowerBound = it.next();
    Object upperBound = it.next();
    arr.add(lowerBound+" - "+upperBound);
}
```

iterator `it` is being incremented twice `it.next()` in a single iteration that finally results in the array that you are getting.

Solution as below:

```
Double lowerBound = neginf;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    // Get element
    Double upperBound = it.next();
    arr.add(lowerBound + " - "+ upperBound);
    lowerBound = upperBound;
}
```